# What item is sold whenever I step on the top left sell shop panel in Crypt of the Necrodancer?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

There is a special shop that allows you to sell items that you have equipped for gold.  I can understand all but one of the panels.

- **North East**: Ring
- **East**: Digging Tool
- **South East**: Weapon
- **South**: Torch
- **South West**: Boots
- **West**: Torso
- **North West**: ???

What is the North West panel supposed to be and what item will it sell?

[image: Crypt of the Necrodancer Sell Shop]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I was asking this question, I figured it out.  By process of elimination, the north west panel is for your **helmet** item.  The panel is a head with long hair.  The head has long hair since the main playable character has long hair (funny since the character pictured is bald).

Comment: Pretty sure they just have short hair there...